# Multiple Destination Inside List SwiftUI

Tags: listview, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I have created a `MenuList`, a `MenuListElementView`and a `MenuListElement`. In my `MenuList`

```
struct MenuList {
static let listData: [MenuListElement] = [
    MenuListElement(elementID: 0, icon: Constants.IconNames.smileyFace, title: Constants.IconTitles.title1, color: Constants.Colors.gray, numbers: 2),... 
 }
```

and so on I have created 10 separate list elements.

In my `MenuListElement`

```
struct MenuListElement: Identifiable {
var id: Int {
    return elementID
}
var elementID: Int
var icon: String
var title: String
var color: Color
var numbers: Int
}
```

In my `MenuListElementView`, I simply designed how each of the list elements must be.
[image]

Finally, I designed this MenuView

[image]

Now, what I want to do is to go to a different destination in each `MenuListElement`when tapped in this code.

```
 NavigationView{
            List(MenuList.listData) { item in
                    MenuListElementView(item: item)
            }
        }
```

Let's say that I want to go to `AuthorView` when Yazarlar is tapped on the `MenuLView` and to `SearchView` when Arama is tapped. I want 10 different destinations `View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my `MenuListElement` to be able to send a view inside with it.

```
struct MenuListElement: Identifiable {
var id: Int {
    return elementID
}
var elementID: Int
var icon: String
var title: String
var color: Color
var numbers: Int
var view: Any
}
```

I have changed my `List` view to

```
List(MenuList.listData) { item in
            Button(action: {
                self.isOpen = true
            }) {
                MenuListElementView(item: item)
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen) {
                        AnyView(_fromValue: item.view)
                    }
            }
        }
```

and changed my `MenuList` to

```
struct MenuList {
static let listData: [MenuListElement] = [
    MenuListElement(elementID: 0, icon: Constants.IconNames.smileyFace, title: Constants.IconTitles.title1, color: Constants.Colors.gray, numbers: 2, view: MembershipView()),...
```

In this way every list element has view information in them so with a button, I can directly pass to a view I want.